# Display values for specific time-frame

Tags: sql, database, oracle, average, self-join

when I run below select:

```
select name, time, value from table1 where name like '%Z' or '%V'
```

I got result:

[image]

**I need to do two things**:

**1**) query will be run every hour, so if we have 12.00.00PM range should be between (11 and 12> PM, if it's 02.00.00AM range will be (01 and 02> AM

**2**) second thing is to display avg(value) for name ending by '%Z' or '%V' into **one row**, but into **two columns**

Below is example of desirable result, when query was run at 12.00.00 PM:

[image]

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`!

Comment: You actually want to show the list of values being averaged, or just the average itself? The time range part is pretty straightfoward; the aggregation is only slightly complicated if you do want the list too. (Also, [please post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/266304), and source data as DDL/DML would be helpful).

Comment: BTW, does your query actually execute?!?

Comment: What does "between (11 and 12> PM" mean - specifically the "12>" part? And 'between' is inclusive. Do you want >= 11 and < 12, or something else?

Comment: @Alex you have right, should be >=11 and <12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for three things, which can be thought of as three steps. Getting the time window is fairly straightforward, and only slightly complicated by your column being a timestamp rather than a date. You implied this will run on the hour, but it's possible it will be slightly afterwards - maybe a second or two? - so it's probably safer to take that into account. You can use [the `trunc()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm) to modify a date value to the required precision, so to only look at the current hour you would truncate to HH[24]. You can then [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions024.htm) that back to a timestamp. And you can use [interval arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208) to find the hour before that:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZR';

select systimestamp,
  trunc(systimestamp, 'HH24') as a,
  cast(trunc(systimestamp, 'HH24') as timestamp) as b,
  cast(trunc(systimestamp, 'HH24') as timestamp) - interval '1' hour as c
from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                   A                   B                       C                      
------------------------------ ------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2017-03-01 09:25:39.342 +00:00 2017-03-01 09:00:00 2017-03-01 09:00:00.000 2017-03-01 08:00:00.000
```

The `alter session` commands are just to control how the different data types are displayed, for comparison. (Don't rely on NLS settings in your real code; use `to_char()` for final formatting of datetime values as strings).

Notice that the result of the truncation is now a date (A in that output), so I've cast it back to a timestamp (B). The range you want is essentially `time >= A and time < B`. And you could use `sysdate` instead of `systimestamp` as the input to `trunc()`.

For your sample data using `systimestamp` or `sysdate` isn't going to find anything, so I'll use a fake fixed time for the rest, generated in a CTE for separation. Where I've used `now` from the CTE, you would use systimestamp or sysdate.

The second part is to get the average for each name within that time period. That's simple aggregation:

```
with fake_time(now) as (
  select timestamp '2017-02-10 13:01:07' from dual
)
select name,
  avg(value) as avg_value,
  cast(trunc(now, 'HH24') as timestamp) as time
from fake_time
join table1 on time >= cast(trunc(now, 'HH24') as timestamp) - interval '1' hour
and time < cast(trunc(now, 'HH24') as timestamp)
group by name, now;

NAME     AVG_VALUE TIME                   
------- ---------- -----------------------
QWER1_Z         20 2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
QWER1_V         35 2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
TEST1_Z         15 2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
TEST1_V         10 2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
```

To pick up the rows you want I've made the fake time 13:00 instead of 12:00. The average you showed for `TEST1_V` was also wrong.

The next stage it pivoting those into the format you wanted, as a single row. For that you can add the root (i.e. `TEST1` or `QWER1`) and the letter (Z or V) as extra columns in the result set, and then use that as the subquery for the [pivot operation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) - this requires 11g or higher:

```
with fake_time(now) as (
  select timestamp '2017-02-10 13:01:07' from dual
)
select z_name, z_value, v_name, v_value, time
from (
  select substr(name, 1, length(name) - 2) as root,
    substr(name, -1) as zv,
    name,
    avg(value) as avg_value,
    cast(trunc(now, 'HH24') as timestamp) as time
  from fake_time
  join table1 on time >= cast(trunc(now, 'HH24') as timestamp) - interval '1' hour
  and time < cast(trunc(now, 'HH24') as timestamp)
  group by substr(name, 1, length(name) - 2), name, now
)
pivot (max(name) as name, max(avg_value) as value for (zv) in ('Z' as z, 'V' as v));

Z_NAME     Z_VALUE V_NAME     V_VALUE TIME                   
------- ---------- ------- ---------- -----------------------
TEST1_Z         15 TEST1_V         10 2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
QWER1_Z         20 QWER1_V         35 2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
```

There may be another step required; in your sample output you included a list of the original values that were averaged, but didn't confirm if you actually wanted those or if they were just to show how the average was caculated to help us understand what you needed to do. If you really do want to include that you can use `listagg()` and concatenation to build up the 'average' string before pivoting:

```
    'avg(' || listagg(value, ',') within group (order by value) || ') = ' || avg(value)
      as avg_value,
```

to get

```
Z_NAME  Z_VALUE              V_NAME  V_VALUE              TIME                   
------- -------------------- ------- -------------------- -----------------------
TEST1_Z avg(10,20) = 15      TEST1_V avg(10) = 10         2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
QWER1_Z avg(20) = 20         QWER1_V avg(30,40) = 35      2017-02-10 13:00:00.000
```

As I said earlier, I've only used the `fake_date` CTE to get a date that matches your sample data. Your real query will be more like:

```
select z_name, z_value, v_name, v_value, time
from (
  select substr(name, 1, length(name) - 2) as root,
    substr(name, -1) as zv,
    name,
    avg(value) as avg_value,
    cast(trunc(sysdate, 'HH24') as timestamp) as time
  from table1
  where time >= cast(trunc(sysdate, 'HH24') as timestamp) - interval '1' hour
  and time < cast(trunc(sysdate, 'HH24') as timestamp)
  group by substr(name, 1, length(name) - 2), name
)
pivot (max(name) as name, max(avg_value) as value for (zv) in ('Z' as z, 'V' as v));
```

Comment: thank you for explanation, but I'm not able to do any alter session :/

Comment: @4est - the alter session is just to control how dates and timestamps are displayed by default in my client, and that was mostly to show the distinction between the two data types. You shouldn't rely on NLS settings anyway; for your final output (if this isn't being consumed by some other process) you should use `to_char()` to format the timestamp values.

Comment: @ alex : what should be instead of 
"select timestamp '2017-02-10 13:01:07' from dual" , into my org query?

Comment: @4est - you won't need the fake_date CTE at all. I said in the question, where I used `now`, use `sysdate` or `systimestamp` in your real query. (You could use a CTE to avoid having to trunc/cast the value multiple times, but that's not necessary for this demo - you can extend this however you need). (And in retrospect, using `now` might be confusing as that's a function in other systems...)

Comment: can you put the correct query? it's much imported for me and I don't want to make any miastake

Comment: OK, added, but you still need to verify it gets the output you expect for your real data.

Comment: No, I already said that was just to set the default for my client, and you should use `to_char()` to explicitly format a date/timestamp as a string for final display. I have no idea what you are dong with the results of this, so I left it as a native timestamp. Your client or whatever executes this will decide how to format that timestamp, unless you add `to_char()` around it.

Comment: thank you Alex, I run it without alter session and I got result, now I need to validate it, thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.Z, T1.V from (
(select avg(values) from table1 where name like '%Z' and time between sysdate and sysdate - interval '1' group by INSTR(name,'Z')) Z,
(select avg(values) from table1 where name like '%V' and time between sysdate and sysdate - interval '1' group by INSTR(name,'V')) V ) T1
```

Comment: I got error: ORA-30089: missing or invalid <datetime field>........when I run only one select I got the same error

Comment: maybe you must use TO_DATE function on time column in query: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: I added: .....interval '1' hour, then one query is working, but whole statment has error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis